# How to create a permanent authentication token with Auth0?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, auth0

I need to create a permanent identifying URL for each user, through which (by visiting it), they will be logged in.

For example:
User1: https://www.example.com/?userToken=gj56u45g64g56uy54g6uyg546
User2: https://www.example.com/?userToken=8o9k7ok9o89k7o9ko8k9o78k9

The functionality is similar how one would identify to an API, or click an email confirmation link, but it has to be permanent or at least with a very long duration, because it will be stored on an NFC chip.

How can I do this within Auth0? (or Oauth 2, because I think that's what they use?)

From some reading that I did, I did not seem to find a way to get a permanent token for a user, and those tokens that I could get, had a maximum life cycle of 24 hours, which is too short for the intended use.

I have done this fairly quickly in a custom way, but within Auth0 I am not sure how it's done.

I read about refresh tokens, but these it seems to me, will need to be written to the NFC chip every time, which I can't do.

Answer (score 0):

When you authenticate, you are given an ID and access token.

You typically use the ID-token to create a long-lived session-cookie, that can live as long as you like. The ID-token is by design a pretty short-lived token, by default like 5 minutes in some systems.

If it is for an embedded system, then there also the device-flow, that is more suitable for devices with a limited UI https://auth0.com/device-flow

I doubt writing JWT tokens from an authorization service is the right approach, as you have to remember that these services typically change/rotate their signing keys, so tokens issued for 6 months ago, might not be accepted today. And for example in a compromise and they are forced to change all their signing-keys, then all your devices will be made useless.

Better approach is to write your own "key" into each device.

Comment: It's not an embedded system, it's just a way to replace typing username + pass with a NFC tap. I could create a solution with my own key etc as you suggest, but this app already is using Auth0 so I need to integrate with it.